# Web scraping a hyperlinked page

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from a local web site. The code collects the table in that Page but I want to also collect the data which is hyperlinked from table "Name of VO/NGO" field.

[image]

This is the main table. Other fields I want are from the page that appears when you click "Name of VO/NGO".

[image]

I read online material but couldn't correct the code.

First output should appear like this and so on the list should be made of each NGO:

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/1"
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable, ws As Worksheet, headers()
    headers = Array("Sr No.", "Name of VO/NGO", "Address", "City","State","Telephone","Mobile No.","Website","Email")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set hTable = html.querySelector("table.dvdtbl")
    Dim td As Object, tr As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    r = 1
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            If r > 3 Then
                For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    .Cells(r - 2, c) = IIf(c = 2, "'" & td.innerText, td.innerText)
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try Debugging the code ? Using `F8` ?

Comment: Yes It is giving error Object variable or block variable not set in line " For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to do to achieve the results you are after.

1. You need to parse the id number from each link to reuse it in post requests.
2. You need to parse csrf token from [this link](https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf) to be used in post requests

finally, you have to use any json converter or script control to dig out individual fields from that json response.

My following attempt can fetch you the json response. All you need to do now is parse the json to meet your requirement:

```
Sub FetchTabularInfo()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim col As Variant, icol As New Collection
    Dim csrf As Variant, I&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/1", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".table tr a[onclick^='show_ngo_info']")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            icol.Add Split(Split(.item(I).getAttribute("onclick"), "(""")(1), """)")(0)
        Next I
    End With

    For Each col In icol
        With Http
            .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf", False
            .send
            csrf = .responseText
        End With

        csrf = Split(Replace(Split(csrf, ":")(1), """", ""), "}")(0)

        With Http
            .Open "POST", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", False
            .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
            .send "id=" & col & "&csrf_test_name=" & csrf
        End With

        Debug.Print Http.responseText
    Next col
End Sub
```

Output of the first lead:

```
{"status":1,"infor":{"0":{"UniqueID":"AN\/2017\/0161456","Mobile":"9476076176","Email":"anaportblair@gmail.com","ngo_url":"http:\/\/www.adityanatyaacademy.com","ngo_name":"AdityaNatyaAcademy","pan_updDocId":"220156","reg_updDocId":"221361","Off_phone1":null,"Major_Activities1":".Drama\nJatrapala\nStreetplays\nAwareness Programe"},"issues_working_db":"","operational_states_db":"ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR ISLANDS, ","operational_district_db":"ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR ISLANDS->South Andaman, "},"member_info":[{"SalCode":null,"FName":"ASHUTOSH KARMAKAR","MName":null,"LName":null,"DesigName":"President","EmailId":"nicorajberg@gmail.com","MobileNo":"9434262953","pan_updDocId":"223392","aadhaar_updDocId":"223393"},{"SalCode":null,"FName":"KAVERI DEBSHARMA","MName":null,"LName":null,"DesigName":"Member","EmailId":"rajeshdebsharma@gmail.com","MobileNo":"9474299901","pan_updDocId":"223400","aadhaar_updDocId":"223401"},{"SalCode":null,"FName":"SATYAJIT BAIN","MName":null,"LName":null,"DesigName":"Asisstant Secretary","EmailId"
:"anaportblair@gmail.com","MobileNo":"9434271746","pan_updDocId":"223408","aadhaar_updDocId":"223409"}],"registeration_info":[{"nr_orgName":"AdityaNatyaAcademy","nr_add":"31 M.G. Road,\nOpp. Sun Sea Resort,\nMiddle Point.","nr_city":"Port Blair","StateName":"ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR ISLANDS","reg_name":"Registrar of Companies","TypeDescription":"Registered Societies (Non-Government)","nr_regNo":"888","nr_updDocId":"0","nr_actName":"Society Registration Act 1860","nr_isFcra":"N","fcrano":"","ngo_reg_date":"05-12-1995"}],"source_info":[{"sourcefund":"S","deptt_name":"Directorate of Art and Culture","purpose":"To Promote Art and Culture in Andaman and Nicobar Islands.","datefrom":"2013-04-01","dateto":"2014-03-31","amount_sanctioned":"25000"},{"sourcefund":"S","deptt_name":"Directorate of Art and Culture","purpose":"To promote Art and Culture","datefrom":"2014-04-01","dateto":"2015-03-31","amount_sanctioned":"25000"},{"sourcefund":"S","deptt_name":"Directorate of Art and Culture","purpose":"To promote Art and Cult
ure","datefrom":"2015-04-01","dateto":"2016-03-31","amount_sanctioned":"35000"},{"sourcefund":"S","deptt_name":"Directorate of Art and Culture","purpose":"To promote Art and Culture","datefrom":"2016-04-01","dateto":"2017-03-31","amount_sanctioned":"25000"}]}
```

Reference to add to execute the above script:

```
Microsoft Html Object Library
Microsoft xml, v6.0
```

Comment: Dear not getting the required output instead a window is opening with a start as <DOCTYPE html>, <html lang= "en">

Comment: That's really embarrassing cause ***[this is](https://filebin.net/kj0e1saykqvkvq4a)*** what I see in the immediate window when I execute the above script.

Comment: Dear I am new to VBA, can you please check.

Comment: Check out the update @werdakloi. It should not behave otherwise now.

Comment: Ok dear but I want to show results in excel sheet like the picture above...please guide